# Custom field value is not getting in observer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, product-attribute, custom-options, products

I have created a custom field in advance inventory in magento 2 product edit but its value is not getting in observer my code is like

```
<fieldset name="stock_data">
               <container name="container_is_discontinued" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group" sortOrder="4200">
                  <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is Discontinued</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">quantity_and_stock_status.container_is_discontinued</item>
                            <item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string">[GLOBAL]</item>
                            <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">${$.provider}:data.product.stock_data.manage_stock</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <field name="is_discontinued" formElement="select">
                        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                        <settings>
                            <scopeLabel>[GLOBAL]</scopeLabel>
                            <label translate="true">Is Discontinued</label>
                            <dataScope>is_discontinued</dataScope>
                        </settings>
                        <formElements>
                            <select>
                                <settings>
                                    <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno"/>
                                </settings>
                            </select>
                        </formElements>
                    </field>
                </container>
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Which event did you use Post code of observer.

Comment: i am using "catalog_product_save_after" event and getting product collection but not my custom attribute value

Comment: Give a try with `$this->getRequest()->getPost();` (Untested) or Try to print post value,. `var_dump($_POST);``

Comment: no its not showing